# what is the best method to create a singleton?

Tags: java

The static inner class can guard against momory leak?

Comment: just because something is a static inner class doesn't make it a singleton. what's your point?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java" book, the *best* (and maybe easiest) way to create a Singleton is to make a single-element enum:

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;

    Singleton() { }
}
```

This way it's guaranteed that:

- the Singleton is thread-safe
- single instance will be created for the application lifespan
- the instance is implicitly `Serializable`.

More info:

- [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)